# How to make Aspect Advise a Junit test in Spring?

Tags: spring, junit, aop

My Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class testAutomationAspect {
    @Before(value="execution(* my.package.*.*(..))")
    public void BeforeTest(){

        System.out.println("?????");
    }
}
```

My Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:context/automation-context.xml"})
public class TestNgExample extends TestCase{

    public void testSomething2() throws java.io.IOException{

        Assert.assertNotNull(null);
    }
```

}

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy  proxy-target-class="true">

        <aop:include name="automationAspect" />
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean id="automationAspect" class="my.package.AutomationAspect" />

</beans>
```

Right now, the aspect doesn't run when the junit runs. My guess is that the xml context doesn't define the Test cases so they are in separate contexts somehow. How would you get the junit test in the same context? I tried using @ContextConfiguration to achieve this. Not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Comment: and if you use the annotation org.junit.Before? instead the aspect?

Answer (score 2):

Spring AOP is proxy-based and only works with Spring Beans. Unless your test class is a Spring bean, it will not work. In order to apply aspects to normal (non Spring Bean) POJOs you can use full-blown AspectJ which works without proxies.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway your problem is that the class TestNgExample is not part of Spring context. Wrap each method in one class and declare it as bean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your test by using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner then all of your aspects, validators and others will work :) `@ContextConfiguration` is ok. You need it to define the test context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

but I am not sure Aspects will work if you attach them to the tests. Maybe it is better to invoke them around Service methods that you are going to test.